# change the repeated comments with word "same" but keep the original ones

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I would like to change the repeated comments with word "same" but keep the original ones and change the ID like below

```
df = {'Key': ['111', '111','111', '222*1','222*2', '333*1','333*2', '333*3'],
      'id' : ['', '','', '1','2', '1','2', '3'],
        'comment': ['wrong sentence', 'wrong sentence','wrong sentence', 'M','M', 'F','F', 'F']}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

print(df)
```

Input :

[image]

the desired output :

[image]

Comment: have you tried the shift method
`df.loc[df.comment == df.comment.shift(), "comment"] = "same"`  and see if it works?

Comment: It works for the first set of the comments. it doesn`t loop through the comment column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact logic is unclear, but you can try:

```
# replace duplicated words per group
df.loc[df[['Key', 'comment']].duplicated(), 'comment'] = 'same'

# update id/Key
m = df['id'].eq('')
df.loc[m, 'id'] = df.groupby('Key').cumcount().add(1)
df.loc[m, 'Key'] += '*'+df['id'].astype(str)
```

Output:

```
     Key id         comment
0  111*1  1  wrong sentence
1  111*2  2            same
2  111*3  3            same
3  222*1  1               M
4  222*2  2               M
5  333*1  1               F
6  333*2  2               F
7  333*3  3               F
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This works for just the first set. what if we have another set of comments with different keys. Can we loop through the comment column

Comment: Yes you would need to use a `for` loop